# vertical align of checkbox

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have this html code, i want to align vertically the checbox in it's span  :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>asdad</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link href="inner_css/account.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    </head>
    <body class="xxx">
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
            <span class="fieldHeader">C++</span>
            <span class="checkboxOfField"><input style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle" type="checkbox"></span>
            <div class="fildtablewrapper">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            0-2
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            2-5
                        </td>
                        <td>
                    5 ומעלה                            
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="radio" name="xxx" value="1"> 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="radio" name="xxx" value="2"> 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="radio" name="xxx" value="3"> 
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this css code:

```
.xxx{
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: center;
}


.fieldWrapper{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 140px;
    background-color: yellow;
    text-align: center;
}

.fieldHeader{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    direction: ltr;
    text-align: center;
}

.checkboxOfField{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    height: 40px;
}

.fildtablewrapper{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

table{
    width: 100%;
}

td{
    width: 33.33%;
}
```

and I still can't vertical align the checkbox, I have searched the we and could not find something that works for me.
Please HELP!

Comment: Mixing external css and inline css is VERY bad practice, probably worse than using inline css on its own. Vertical-align works best when its element also has display:table-cell; although this will not work if you NEED display:inline.. there are a number of possible workarounds including the answer that mentions line-height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this to your `.checkboxOfField` style:

`line-height: 40px;`

that will make the checkbox centered to the 40px height of the span

Comment: It works on  jsFiddle but on my chrome browser it is not working

Comment: instead of the `line-height:40px;` you can add this line of css and see if it works for you: `.checkboxOfField input[type=checkbox] { margin:10px auto;}` NOTE: default checkboxes are 20px X 20px so in order to vertically center in a 40px high span add 10px top and bottom margin.

Comment: Ok, but why the height-line dose not work on chrome and other browsers?

Comment: well it's actually `line-height` not `height-line` and i am not sure why it's not working for you, but it works for me in all browsers (chrome 21, firefox 15, even IE8)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding following in your CSS file

```
.checkboxOfField input {
height: 100%;
}
```